# Phone activation problems

Tags: icloud, iphone, find-my-iphone

Ok I got this Iphone4 and it s already got a apple ID and it wont let me sign in for my apple ID so im waiting to see what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Did you buy it used? It sounds like the previous owner did not sign out of iCloud and turn off Find my iPhone before he sold it to you. If you can contact him and have him do it from iCloud.com, you'll be fine. If not, the phone is useless.